# Regarding multiple master pages in mvc4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]I have one master page named **Site.Master** in which I have tabs logic

```
  <div id="menubar">
        @Html.SimpleNav(new[] {
            new SimpleNavItem{Text="Home", Action="Index", Controller = "Home",GetSelected = ((a, c) => (c == "Home" && a == "Index"))},
            new SimpleNavItem{Text="Blog", Action="Index", Controller = "Blog", GetSelected = ((a, c) => (c == "Blog" && a == "Index"))},
            new SimpleNavItem{Text="About", Action="About", Controller = "Home", GetSelected = ((a, c) => c == "Home" && a == "About")},
            new SimpleNavItem{Text="Contact", Action="Contact", Controller = "Home", GetSelected = ((a, c) => c == "Home" && a == "Contact")}
        }) %>
    </div>
```

Tab logic class file code is this

```
 public static class SimpleNavExtensions
{
    public static string SimpleNav(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<SimpleNavItem> navItems)
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        string controller = html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        string action = html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

        TagBuilder ul = new TagBuilder("ul");
        ul.AddCssClass("clearfix");

        StringBuilder listBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        TagBuilder li = null;
        TagBuilder a = null;
        foreach (var item in navItems)
        {
            a = new TagBuilder("a");
            a.Attributes.Add("href", urlHelper.Action(item.Action, item.Controller));
            a.InnerHtml = item.Text;

            li = new TagBuilder("li");
            if (item.GetSelected != null && item.GetSelected(action, controller))
                li.AddCssClass("sel");
            li.InnerHtml = a.ToString();

            listBuilder.Append(li.ToString());
        }

        ul.InnerHtml = listBuilder.ToString();

        return ul.ToString();
    }
}

public class SimpleNavItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public Func<string, string, bool> GetSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Now 3 other page will inherit Site.Master
For Example About.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">About</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>About</h2>

</asp:Content>
```

Now I have another master page **NAMED MAIN.MASTER** I want that my site.master should inherit from main.master page..so what should

Comment: Are you using `RazorEngine`?

Comment: I have shown the code of .aspx page...but I want to do this in Razor engine..how it is possible?

Comment: If you want to do this in razor then, you will use `Layouts` instead of master pages. Also, your class `SimpleNavExtensions` seems to be pointless to me as we can directly have html instead of this hard work...

Comment: ok I will use layouts but how to specify two layouts I mean how to specify one layout to other layout???I have used that class file for applying css to current tabs selected..

Comment: Actually, after clicking on `company` tab, you will bee loading a new `View` right? So, just use another `Layout` for that view and load it.

Comment: No on click of company tab I will load view of purchase from purchase controller..which will invoke Index action result from purchase controller..and that purchase index view contains MASTER LAYOUT OF SITE..SO ON TOP OF IT.how can i load MAIN LAYOUT???CAN U EXPLAIN ME WITH HELP OF SAMPLE CODE

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29741/discussion-between-rajubhai-and-bhushan-firake)